# Why can't I use ! _displayCheckBox.value which is non-null MutableLiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin

Code A works well, I think the `_displayCheckBox.value` should be non-null, you can see Image A which is from the prompt of Android Studio.

I think I have initial the value of `_displayCheckBox` using  `private val _displayCheckBox = MutableLiveData(false)`, so I think  `_displayCheckBox.value` will be non-null MutableLiveData.

But Code B cause the error *"Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Boolean?"*, why?

**Code A**

```
private val _displayCheckBox = MutableLiveData(false)
val displayCheckBox : LiveData<Boolean> = _displayCheckBox

//Switch CheckBox On or Off
fun switchCheckBoxShowStatus(){
    _displayCheckBox.value?.let {
        _displayCheckBox.value = !it
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
private val _displayCheckBox = MutableLiveData(false)
val displayCheckBox : LiveData<Boolean> = _displayCheckBox

//Switch CheckBox On or Off
fun switchCheckBoxShowStatus(){
   _displayCheckBox.value = ! _displayCheckBox.value // It cause error.
}
```

**Image A**

[image]

**Added Content**

I will always get "The value is false" for Code C.
So I think _aa.value will be non-null when I use `val _aa = MutableLiveData(false)`, right?

**Code C**

```
 val _aa = MutableLiveData(false)
 Log.e("My","The  value is "+_aa.value?:"null ")
```

Comment: @Slaw In the case of LiveData, the return type is explicitly `@Nullable T` because the `value` actually can be null even if the type is not nullable, where null indicates that no value has been set yet. A return type of `Boolean!` would not show an error if you treated it as non-nullable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ah yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LiveData.getValue()` is specifically annotated as returning a nullable value, and so Kotlin interprets it as nullable. It is nullable because the value actually *is* null if it hasn't been set yet.

If you want to toggle its value, you can provide a fallback value for when it's null. And if you give it an initial value when you instantiate it, you know the value will never be used.

Or you could create your own non-nullable BooleanLiveData that enforces an initial value. By subclassing, you can narrow the returned type of `getValue` from `Boolean?` to `Boolean`.

```
class BooleanLiveData(initialValue: Boolean): MutableLiveData<Boolean>() {
    init {
        value = initialValue
    }

    override fun getValue(): Boolean = super.getValue() ?: false
}
```

Or you can use StateFlow instead of LiveData. StateFlow enforces an initial value.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean  the value of _`displayCheckBox` maybe null even if I write the code `private val _displayCheckBox = MutableLiveData(false)`

Comment: Question: What if OP did `private val _displayCheckBox: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(false)`? In other words, make the type explicit. Would Kotlin be able to tell that the value is not nullable then? Or does the fact that the class is defined in Java still get in the way? I would test this but I don't have a suitable environment at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: I think you're both asking the same question. And the answer is no. There's no way Kotlin's compiler can know all the inner workings of the class and determine that the value must not be null because some method was called on the object earlier. It goes purely by the nullability annotation that says the return value is nullable. If you know that you have already set the value at least once, or instantiated the class with an initial value, then you as the programmer know it will never be null (because you've read the Javadocs for the class so you know the author of the class made that promise).

Comment: So in this case, you know more than the compiler. You could safely use `!!` in this situation. But it would be preferable to use `?: error("Forgot to set initial value")` instead of `!!` just in case you made a mistake, so you'll get an exception that tells you exactly what to fix.